# Can't indentify protractor elements inside iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, protractor

My iframe:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://csfe-preprod.bankid.no/CentralServerFEJS/a?cid=KF3c3j2c6XcWLdRN" title="BankID"></iframe>
```

Inside it is the element i want to interact with.
The problem is that with every tutorial/post on google/a couple on stackoverflow i've found, i just get the "element not found by selector" error every time.

Some i've tried: (i've tried multiple but i've erased them)

```
var driver = browser.driver;
var loc = by.css('iframe[title="BankID"]');
var el = driver.findElement(loc);
browser.switchTo().frame(el);


browser.switchTo().frame(element(by.xpath('//*[@id="bankid-container"]/iframe')).getWebElement());
```

I can't seem to understand why i can't interact with the elements. In the browser's console i can easly indentify them with a simple jquery css selector $('iframe[title="BankID"]') and multiple others, they work, i know they do but i can't seem to be able to interact with them.

I've tried I think all the possible ways of changing the frame, i'm really at my edge here...

Comment: is the iframe same origin as containing page?

Comment: Not gonna lie, i have no ideea, i've never worked with iframes before, if you could help me with more info maybe i can tell you

Comment: it's your webpage, isn't it? I take it `https://csfe-preprod.bankid.no` is your site?

Comment: it's a 3rd party page that my main pages takes me to